# Bounty name overflow

Tags: bug, design, bounties

Was reading [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result/6841479#6841479) and saw this char overflow:

[image]